# How to use LVM to separate large data?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, lvm

I have an ultrabook with two discs, an HDD with `500GB` and an SSD with `32GB`.

My SSD is partitioned for `/boot`, `/` and `/efi`, and my HDD is for `SWAP` and `/media/userdata` (mainly, media).

I was thinking of have `/home` on a logical partition between the HDD and SSD (should be `/dev/sda4` and `/dev/sdb2`), but I think the HDD io would impact in my performance (for programs startup, user configurations, etc.).

So, is it possible to make LVM write large files (`> 4MB`, by example, or according to file type) to HDD, and small ones (or every `.hidden` file/dir) to SSD?

Comment: I don't think LVM can do this, but you could also consider using `bcache`, recently merged in the kernel, which will use ssd for caching automatically.

Comment: I see. But how does LVM behave with diferent disk sizes? Since my HDD has 500GB and SSD about 20GB (not mirrored), is it possible to foresee  (or add some rule) where will it write?

Comment: @Paul, `bcache` seems a good approach, but as I can see, the cache device starts at `zero`, so every first-read is from HDD. So it may not help to apps startup.